# JSON отправка логина и пароля

Tags: java, android, json

Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я отправляю логин и пароль? Я должен через java отправить чтоб получилось так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```
    @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();
            map.put("login", txtLogin.getText().toString());
            map.put("password",txtPassword.getText().toString());
           return map;
        }
    };
```

Но я получаю ошибку 422

Comment: Не очень понятно, что должен делать приведенный код и зачем он вообще Вам нужен. Воспользуйтесь Gson или Moshi или еще какой-нибудь библиотекой, умеющей переводить обычные классы в формат json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему заменив тот код на:

```
          `public byte[] getBody()  throws AuthFailureError{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            String body = null;
            try
            {
                jsonObject.put("login", txtLogin.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("password", txtPassword.getText().toString());

                body = jsonObject.toString();
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try
            {
                return body.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            {
                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }`  и получил ответ 200 ОК
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй обернуть эти данные в какой-то класс, например `Credentials`.

```
public class Credentials{

private String name;
private String password;

public Credentials(String name, String password){
...
}

}
```

И затем возвращать объект `Credentials` вместо `Map`.
Ошибку выдаёт из-за того, что `toString()` у мапы не подходит под структуру JSON'а

Answer (score 0):

Смотря с какой библиотекой для осуществления запросов вы работаете. Через  Retrofit вроде так проще всего так:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("login", txtLogin.getText().toString());
object.put("login", txtPassword.getText().toString());
return object;
```

Comment: что значит нельзя делать return?